# Weird ordering of bytes from one pixel to the next in simple PIL bitmap. What is likely wrong?

Tags: python, bitmap, python-imaging-library, endianness

Here is the code.

```
import os
import io
import PIL
#import pyximport;  pyximport.install()
#from pixel_tools import PixelsBMP
from PIL import Image, ImageGrab

# TODO convert to Cython

class PixelsBMP:
    def __init__(self, img):
        if isinstance(img, str):
            img = Image.open(img)

        with io.BytesIO() as bytes_io:
            img.save(bytes_io, 'BMP')
            data = bytes_io.getvalue() 
            offset = int.from_bytes(data[10:14], byteorder='little', signed=False)
            data = data[offset:]        # pixels start here

        self.data = data
        self.width = img.width
        self.height = img.height
        self.bands = 3 if img.mode == 'RGB' else 4

    def debugPrintPixels(self):
        import sys
        d = self.data
        print('width:', self.width)
        print('height:', self.height)
        print('bands (alpha=>4):', self.bands)
        for y in range(0, self.height):
            for x in range(0, self.width):
                offs = self.width * self.bands * y + x
                sys.stdout.write('(' + str(d[offs]) + ',' + str(d[offs + 1]) + ',' + str(d[offs + 2]) + ((',' + str(d[offs + 3])) if self.bands == 4 else '') + ')')
            print()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    subpx = PixelsBMP('images/PixelsBMP_test_subImage.png')
    subpx.debugPrintPixels()

    ##pixels = PixelsBMP('images/PixelsBMP_test_superImage.png')

    ##point = pixels.exactSubpixelSearch(subpx)

    #print(point)
    print('test done')
```

What it prints is:

```
width: 7
height: 3
bands (alpha=>4): 4
(100,50,25,255)(50,25,255,100)(25,255,100,50)(255,100,50,25)(100,50,25,255)(50,25,255,100)(25,255,100,50)
(100,50,25,255)(50,25,255,100)(25,255,100,50)(255,100,50,25)(100,50,25,255)(50,25,255,100)(25,255,100,50)
(100,50,25,255)(50,25,255,100)(25,255,100,50)(255,100,50,25)(100,50,25,255)(50,25,255,100)(25,255,100,50)
None
test done
```

For this 7x3 navy blue bitmap.  Pixels are: `(25, 50, 100)` solid RGB.

---

(It's small, right after this line):

[image: 7x3 navy blue bitmap]

---

So, the BGR ordering isn't shocking or significant here, but the fact that the order changes from the first pixel to the second:
`(100,50,25,255)(50,25,255,100)`.

I'm lazy tonight.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue:

`offs = self.width * self.bands * y + x`

in the debugPrint routine should be:

`offs = self.width * self.bands * y + x * self.bands`

as clearly each pixel is bands wide.

Output of the printer is correct now.